# WhatsApp Cloud API - Unable to verify webhook signature

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When I receive a webhook event I try to verify the signature as mentioned in the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started#create-endpoint:%7E:text=Validating%20Payloads,payload%20is%20genuine.), sometimes the verification is successful and sometimes not.

What I'm doing wrong?

```
    static createSha256Hash(data: string, key: string): string {

        if (isEmpty(data)){
            throw new ValidationException();
        }

        const sha256Hasher = crypto.createHmac('sha256', key);

        return sha256Hasher.update(data).digest('hex');
    }
```

```
public validateWebhookSignature(requestContext: RequestContextModel): void {

        const signature = requestContext?.headers?.['X-Hub-Signature-256'].replace('sha256=', '');
        const body = JSON.stringify(requestContext?.body);

        const hash = CryptoUtil.createSha256Hash(body, this._appSecret);
        if (!signature || !hash) {
            throw new ValidationException();
        } else if (signature !== hash) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably due to what it says, regarding generation of the signature _"using an escaped unicode version of the payload, with lowercase hex digits."_ Try and get the _raw_ request body content, before it was parsed by anything else, instead of encoding the already decoded body as JSON again yourself.

Comment: @CBroe It still does not work. Although I found something interesting: when I receive a webhook with text only, the verification succeeds, but when I receive a webhook with a document or image, the verification fails.

Comment: I am not been able to verify even in text only request. Is your `this._appSecret` same as you verify in subscribe request with `hub.verify_token` query param?

Comment: My bad, app secret is another parameter that we need to pull from facebook application settings